# How to define a docker cli service in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that runs a few services.

```
services:

  cli:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/cli/Dockerfile

    volumes:
      - ./drupal8site:/var/www/html/drupal8site


  drupal:
    container_name: drupal
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/DockerFile.drupal
      args:
        DOC_ROOT: /var/www/html/drupal8site
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./drupal8site:/var/www/html/drupal8site
    restart: always
    environment:
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html/drupal8site/web    

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

I would like to add another service which will be a container in which I could run CLI commands (composer, drush for drupal, php, etc).

The following Dockerfile was how I initially defined the cli service but it stops right after it is run. How do I define it so it is part of my docker-compose, shares my mounted volume, and I can interactively connect to it and run CLI commands on it ?

```
FROM php:7.2-cli

#various programs
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install vim --assume-yes \
    && apt-get install git --assume-yes \
    && apt-get install mysql-client --assume-yes


CMD ["bash"]
```

Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: what is the purpose of you cli : perform queries (through command lines) targetting mysql and drupal, or have a container that will also store some additional functionalities that will use both previous services? Your CMD here with a bash cannot work, because it is not interactive... but before I go further, please answer this first question

Comment: I suspect that my CMD is wrong. I just don't know if I should put a CMD at all. The purpose of the CLI container is to run various commands : composer require for packages on the mounted volume, sqldump from that DB, clear the drupal cache etc.   My problem is how to define a container that doesn't need to run a process in the background but I use interactively , and yet is defined as a part of my docker-compose file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run automated scripts on docker images this is obviously a job for a ci-pipeline. You can use CloudFoundry or OpenStack to do this.

But there are many other questions in this post:

1.) How can i share my mounted volume:

You can pass a volume with the -v option to a container. e.g.:

```
docker run -it -d -v $(pwd)/localFolder:/exposedFolderFromDocker mydockerhub/myawesomeimage
```

2.) Can I interactively connect to it and run CLI commands on it

```
docker exec -it docker_cli_1 bash
```

I recommend to implement features of an docker-image to the individual docker-images Dockerfile. For example copying and running a prepared shell-script:

```
# your Dockerfile
FROM php:7.2-cli

#various programs
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install vim --assume-yes \
    && apt-get install git --assume-yes \
    && apt-get install mysql-client --assume-yes

# individual changes
    COPY your_script.sh /
    RUN  chown root:root /your_script.sh && \
         chmod 0755 /your_script.sh
    CMD ["/your_script.sh"]

# a folder to expose
VOLUME /exposedFolderFromDocker

CMD ["bash"]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll clarify my question - my docker-compose works fine for all the services. I'm just trying to add to it an image to run CLI commands on.  I don't understand if it should be part of the docker-compose - and if so - what CMD should it run ? Cause I want to use it as an interactive shell (all the services are running a process that isn't interactive)

Comment: 'docker exec -it docker_cli_1 bash' will give you a terminal for your cli-service. Instead of installing things manually (changing the docker image) with the console you can extend your Dockerfile to add things, e.g. by the way i described upon.

Comment: CMD ["bash"] makes the docker-image offering a terminal to connect via 'docker exec -it docker_cli_1 bash'.
What you are trying to do is part of the Dockerfile and can not be configured within a docker-compose.yml, as I know ;)

Comment: But 'docker exec -it docker_cli_1 bash' will only work if the container is running. In my case it isn't running cause it has no running process - it is a CLI service.  So that's my question again - I want to have an image for running CLI commands - how should it be defined and run ? (if it's a part of the docker-compose then what CMD should it run, if at all ? )

Comment: You can do docker run -it instead of docker exec. This will do what you need but for a non running container. You can also encapsulate your queries within shell functions (in your .bashrc / .profile), such as  function dosomething () { (docker run -ti --rm -v ${HOME}:/root -v $(pwd):/git docker-cli_bash "$@") }, the call it with dosomething --with --extra parameters

Comment: But if I run it with 'docker run' how do I expose it to the services defined in 'docker-compose' ? I want the CLI to have access to the 'mysql' service for instance.